Despliegue en github
Alguno ha tenido este problema?, ya le he agregado los indices tanto en firebase como en el archivo de indices , tambien le he agreado los roles en reglas de firebase
i  deploying firestore
i  firestore: reading indexes from firestore.indexes.json...
i  cloud.firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
⚠  [W] 73:14 - Unused function: min.
⚠  [W] 75:9 - Invalid variable name: request.
⚠  [W] 76:9 - Invalid variable name: request.
⚠  [W] 79:14 - Unused function: max.
⚠  [W] 81:9 - Invalid variable name: request.
⚠  [W] 82:9 - Invalid variable name: request.
⚠  [W] 268:9 - Invalid variable name: isB2B.
✔  cloud.firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
i  firestore: deploying indexes...
i  firestore: there are 5 indexes defined in your project that are not present in your firestore indexes file. To delete them, run this command with the --force flag.
         
Error: Pass the --force flag to use this command in non-interactive mode
i  firestore: uploading rules firestore.rules...

